# Chopping a number

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error

Iv'e been trying to understand this really really simple concept of number chopping.

Let's say that I have a system which is able to save decimal numbers with 3 significant figures and uses the chopping strategy.
The system should evaluate the following value: $ (\frac{1}{8})^2$. The true value is is obviously 0.015625, but my system saves the number as 0.01.

Shouldn't it be 0.0156? as far as I understand, $0.01$ has only 1 significant digits while $0.0156$ has 3, so why isn't the second one the saved value?

Thanks!

Comment: Which "system" are you talking about? Afaik, your expected result should be the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

$0.01$ has only one significant digit, since leading zeroes are insignificant. The correct answer should indeed be $0.0156$.

It seems to me that whatever "system" you are talking about erroneously treats all digits as significant.

Comment: What reason do you have to believe your system "is able to save decimal numbers with 3 significant figures"?  It appears to be saving to **three digit** accuracy  instead.

Comment: @user247327 I think this should be a comment on the original question and not the answer.